# How to filter all directories and sub directories of a directory with a name using apache-commons-io FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs?

Tags: java, apache-commons-io

I have to filter two particular folder paths recursively from a large directory which has many subdirectories using FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs method. So what filters I have to use.

For example, I want to filter all the directory subdirectory paths of directories "results" & "logs" recursively.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried the nameFileFilter but it is filtering only for one directory, it's not filtering recursively.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    IOFileFilter filter1 = 
FileFilterUtils.notFileFilter(FileFilterUtils.nameFileFilter("results", 
null));
IOFileFilter filter2 
=FileFilterUtils.notFileFilter(FileFilterUtils.nameFileFilter("logs", 
null));
FileFilter filter = FileFilterUtils.and(filter1, filter2);
List<File> filteredFiles = (List<File>)FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs(new 
File(args[0]), TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE, (IOFileFilter)fileFilter);

For( File file : filteredFiles) {
    System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
}
}
```

I need to filter all the directories and subdirectories with the name "results" & "logs"

Answer (score 0):

Following code help you to filtering file recursively.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    IOFileFilter filter1 = FileFilterUtils.notFileFilter(FileFilterUtils.nameFileFilter("results"));
    IOFileFilter filter2 = FileFilterUtils.notFileFilter(FileFilterUtils.nameFileFilter("logs"));

    FileFilter filter = FileFilterUtils.andFileFilter(filter1, filter2);

    Collection<File> filteredFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(new File("/media/data/test-file-io"),
        TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE, (IOFileFilter) filter);

    for (File file : filteredFiles) {
      System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
  }
```

Here i use following dependency of common-io

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```